# (opencv) merge contours together

Tags: merge, contour

I am doing a real time motion detection program. I find that there are a lot of contour made in my different image after i used background subtraction method . i would like to ask is there any method that can merge these contour together or make a larger rect contain all the contours?

the case now i have been done
http://singhgaganpreet.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/motioncolour.jpg
My code is here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <OpenCV/cv.h>
#include <OPenCV/highgui.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

CvRect rect;
CvSeq* contours = 0;
CvMemStorage* storage = NULL;
CvCapture *cam;
IplImage *currentFrame, *currentFrame_grey, *differenceImg, *oldFrame_grey;

bool first = true;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   //Create a new movie capture object.
   cam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

   //create storage for contours
   storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

   //capture current frame from webcam
   currentFrame = cvQueryFrame(cam);

   //Size of the image.
   CvSize imgSize;
   imgSize.width = currentFrame->width;
   imgSize.height = currentFrame->height;

   //Images to use in the program.
   currentFrame_grey = cvCreateImage( imgSize, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);                           

   while(1)
   {
          currentFrame = cvQueryFrame( cam );
          if( !currentFrame ) break;

          //Convert the image to grayscale.
          cvCvtColor(currentFrame,currentFrame_grey,CV_RGB2GRAY);

          if(first) //Capturing Background for the first time
          {
                 differenceImg = cvCloneImage(currentFrame_grey);
                 oldFrame_grey = cvCloneImage(currentFrame_grey);
                 cvConvertScale(currentFrame_grey, oldFrame_grey, 1.0, 0.0);
                 first = false;
                 continue;
          }

          //Minus the current frame from the moving average.
          cvAbsDiff(oldFrame_grey,currentFrame_grey,differenceImg);

          //bluring the differnece image
          cvSmooth(differenceImg, differenceImg, CV_BLUR);             

          //apply threshold to discard small unwanted movements
          cvThreshold(differenceImg, differenceImg, 25, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

          //find contours
          cvFindContours( differenceImg, storage, &contours );

          //draw bounding box around each contour
          for(; contours!=0; contours = contours->h_next)
          {
                 rect = cvBoundingRect(contours, 0); //extract bounding box for current contour

                 //drawing rectangle
                 cvRectangle(currentFrame,                  
                              cvPoint(rect.x, rect.y),    
                              cvPoint(rect.x+rect.width, rect.y+rect.height),
                              cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0),
                              2, 8, 0);                 
          }

          //display colour image with bounding box
          cvShowImage("Output Image", currentFrame);

          //display threshold image
          cvShowImage("Difference image", differenceImg);

          //New Background
          cvConvertScale(currentFrame_grey, oldFrame_grey, 1.0, 0.0);

          //clear memory and contours
          cvClearMemStorage( storage );
          contours = 0;

          //press Esc to exit
          char c = cvWaitKey(33);
          if( c == 27 ) break;

   }

   // Destroy the image & movies objects
   cvReleaseImage(&oldFrame_grey);
   cvReleaseImage(&differenceImg);
   cvReleaseImage(&currentFrame);
   cvReleaseImage(&currentFrame_grey);
   //cvReleaseCapture(&cam);

   return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 10):

Did you try this?

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
points.insert(points.end(), contour1.begin(), contour1.end());
points.insert(points.end(), contour2.begin(), contour2.end());
convexHull(cv::Mat(points), contour);
```

PS. For some applications, it may be better to use approxPoly() rather than convexHull(). Just try both.

PPS. Try smoothing the resulting contour with gaussian. It also can be helpful.

Comment: No, we switched to c++

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar problem. In my case I created an empty sequence then I filled it with the points of each contour, after that I fitted a bounding ellipse with that sequence.
Here is my code segment...

```
CvMemStorage *storage = cvCreateMemStorage ();
CvMemStorage *storage1 = cvCreateMemStorage ();
CvSeq *contours = 0;

//find contour in BInv
cvFindContours (BInv, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE ,cvPoint(0,0)); 

//creating empty sequence of CvPoint
CvSeq* seq = cvCreateSeq(CV_SEQ_ELTYPE_POINT/*| CV_SEQ_KIND_SET | CV_SEQ_FLAG_SIMPLE*/,sizeof(CvSeq),sizeof(CvPoint),storage1);

//populating seq with all contours
for(; contours!=0; contours = contours->h_next)
  for(int i=0;i<contours->total;i++)
     {  
         CvPoint* p;
        p = (CvPoint*)cvGetSeqElem (contours, i );
        cvSeqPush(seq,p);   
      }

//bounding box and drawing
CvBox2D bbox=cvMinAreaRect2(seq, NULL );
cvEllipseBox(color,bbox,cvScalarAll(0),5,8,0);
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge contours on the basis of distance apart then you can do something like this:

```
    struct hash_pair {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    size_t operator()(const pair<T1, T2>& p) const
    {
        auto hash1 = hash<T1>{}(p.first);
        auto hash2 = hash<T2>{}(p.second);

        if (hash1 != hash2) {
            return hash1 ^ hash2;
        }

        return hash1;
    }
};
void findPixelsNearby(unordered_map<pair<int, int>,bool,hash_pair>&res, Point px,int pxlVal) {
    for (int itr1 = (px.x) - pxlVal; itr1 <= (px.x) + pxlVal; itr1++) {
        for (int itr2 = (px.y - pxlVal); itr2 <= (px.y) + pxlVal; itr2++) {
            res[{itr1, itr2}] = true;
        }
    }
}
unordered_map<pair<int, int>, bool, hash_pair> createSets(vector<Point2f>Contour, int rect) {
    unordered_map<pair<int,int>,bool,hash_pair>res;
    for (auto tra : Contour) {
        Point px = (Point)tra;
        findPixelsNearby(res,px,rect);
    
    }

    return res;
}

//void drawContour(Mat& img, vector<Point2f>s1,int px,int py,int pz) {
//  for (auto x : s1) {
//      line(img, x, x, Scalar(px, py, pz), 4, 0);
//
//  }
//  resShow("temp",img,1);
    
//}

bool hasCommon(unordered_map<pair<int,int>,bool,hash_pair>s1, unordered_map<pair<int, int>, bool, hash_pair>s2){
    for (auto x : s1) {
        if (s2.find(x.first) != s2.end()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
                                                            
void MergeContours(Mat image, vector<Contour>&usableContours,int distance_considered, vector<Contour>& finalContours) {
    

    int numberContours = usableContours.size();
    vector<vector<int>>ids_for_contour_merge(numberContours);
    vector<unordered_map<pair<int, int>, bool, hash_pair>>ContourSets;  
    vector<bool>boolVals(numberContours,false); 

    for (int i = 0; i < numberContours; i++) {
        ContourSets.push_back(createSets(usableContours[i].points, distance_considered/2));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberContours; i++) {
        
        if (boolVals[i] == false) {
            boolVals[i] = true;
            for (int j = i+1; j < numberContours; j++) {
                if (boolVals[j] == false) {
                    
                    if(hasCommon(ContourSets[i], ContourSets[j])==true){
                        ContourSets[i].insert(ContourSets[j].begin(), ContourSets[j].end());
                        boolVals[j] = true;
                        ids_for_contour_merge[i].push_back(j);
                        j = i;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    vector<bool>Visited(ids_for_contour_merge.size(), false);
    
    for (int mr = 0; mr < ids_for_contour_merge.size(); mr++) {
        if (Visited[mr] == false) {
            vector<Point2f>temp=usableContours[mr].points;
            if (ids_for_contour_merge[mr].size() > 0) {
                for (int mc = 0; mc < ids_for_contour_merge[mr].size(); mc++) {

                    int valPtr = ids_for_contour_merge[mr][mc];
                    
                    copy(usableContours[valPtr].points.begin(), usableContours[valPtr].points.end(), std::back_inserter(temp));
                    Visited[valPtr] = true;
                    

                }
            }
            else {
                Visited[mr] = true;
            }
            Contour newCtr;
            newCtr.points = temp;
            finalContours.push_back(newCtr);
        }
        
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////DRAWING CONTOURS
        /*for (auto x : finalContours) {
            cout <<"CONTOURS FINAL SIZE IS : " <<x.points.size()<<endl;
            int px = 0;
            int py = 0;
            int pz = 0;
            drawContour(image, x.points, ((px+rand())%255), ((py + rand()) % 255), ((pz + rand()) % 255));
        
        }*/
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


}
```

More On Github: https://github.com/HimanshuYadav117/Merge-Contours/blob/main/MergeContours.cpp