# OpenCV - find object shape

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection, object-detection, canny-operator

I'm learning OpenCV and I've reached a point where no matter what I do, I get stucked.
What I'm trying to do is to isolate an object (rectangular object) from its background.

An example is the following picture of a battery:
[image: battery-picture]

I want to mask that image so that the only thing that remains is the object.

I've tried the following:

- Thresholding
- Detect edges using Canny
- Find Contours
- Get the bigger one

But I'm getting some strange area as the bigger one. Here are the resulting pictures:

- Canny
  [image: canny edges]
- Largest Contour
  [image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main( int, char** argv )
{
Mat src, srcGray,srcBlur,srcCanny;

string file = "samsung";
src = imread(file + ".jpg");
cvtColor(src, srcGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
//bilateralFilter(srcGray, srcBlur,11, 17, 17);
srcBlur = srcGray.clone();
imshow("Filtered", srcBlur);
imwrite(file+"-filtered.jpg",srcBlur);

Canny(srcBlur, srcCanny, 0, 100, 3, true);
imshow("Canny", srcCanny);
imwrite(file+"-canny.jpg",srcCanny);


vector< vector <Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
findContours( srcCanny.clone(), contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image


int largest_contour_index=0;
int largest_area=0;
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if(a>largest_area){
    largest_area=a;
    largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
    }
 }


Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0)); //create destination image
drawContours( dst,contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255,0,0),CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
imshow("Largest", dst);
imwrite(file+"-largest.jpg",dst);

waitKey();
}
```

This piece of code was intended to get the 'mask' of the object then masking should be applied but I can't move forward because I can't detect the object

My goal is to detect rectangular objects (only one object per image) in different images.

The idea was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv), but I can't manage to get that code to work with a lesser contrast image like mine.

I've also try [this](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/05/05/building-pokedex-python-opencv-perspective-warping-step-5-6/) wich is pretty much the same as I want.

I want to isolate a rectangular object (wich should be the bigger one in the image)

Thanks in advance!

PS: Although I can translate Python to C++ I would appreciate the answer directly in C++ so I can test it faster.

Comment: did you try [Hough transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html)?

Comment: You need to be aware of two things: 1) no image processing method can guess which "object" you want (for instance, are you after the battery or the label ?) So some selection rule must be there, at least implicitly. 2) state of the art still doesn't give us good segmentation methods.

Comment: welcome to non-trivial computer vision. Cases where neither foreground nor background can be controlled (e.g. by fixed camera, limited target objects, lighting, etc.) are in general quite hard to solve. If you can make some assumptions (e.g. target objects are rectangular) there might be better chances.

Comment: @slawekwin I'm not very familiar with Hough Lines. Maybe you could post a solution?.

Comment: About the assumptions the object will always be a rectangle, we don't know yet which one but the idea is to grab a picture with this rectangle, remove its background fix perspective if needed (skew) and then process it. But you're right the big problem is dealing with lighting conditions and any kind of background

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I hacked together, sorry, it's in Python :)

First, resize the image to 1/4 of the original size (probably going to work without resizing, although with different parameters) and apply median blur:

```
w, h, c = img_in.shape #img_in is the input image
resize_coeff = 0.25
img = cv2.resize(img_in, (int(resize_coeff*h), int(resize_coeff*w)))
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 15)
```

[image]

What's good about median blur is that it removes most of the noise and tiny unnecessary details like those blue marker lines, while keeping the edges of larger shapes non-blurred. Now, let's apply Canny edge detection:

```
img = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
```

[image]

Unfortunately, there are some tiny gaps in our edges, but that can be fixed with dilate/erode:

```
kernel = np.ones((17, 17), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, 1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, 1)
```

[image]

Now we can find our contours, take the largest one by area, and it's probably going to be what we want:

```
img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
max_index, max_area = max(enumerate([cv2.contourArea(x) for x in contours]), key = lambda x: x[1])
max_contour = contours[max_index]
```

Drawing it on top of the original (scaled) image, we get this:

```
img_out = cv2.resize(img_in, (int(resize_coeff*h), int(resize_coeff*w)))
cv2.drawContours(img_out, [max_contour], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

[image]

By some simple contour smoothing we can easily get rid of the wires on top, if we want to. Don't know what to do with the shadow at the bottom, though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No problem is in Python I will convert it to C++ and the add it to your post if you don't mind. I'll test it and let you know. Dumb question: if I resize the image and find its contour, is there a way to take that contour 'back' to the original size image? So after removing the background I can process the high res image

Comment: Yes, just multiply every coordinate of the contour by 4 (e. g. reciprocal for the initial scaling value).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer @Headcrab. Shows some useful tricks. For anyone else wondering the `cv2.approxPolyDP` function is quite effective at smoothing out the contour.

Answer (score 2):

Your input image is too big to find rough setimate of contours. For higher resolution images, output will be more fine detailed. In high resolution case, theere is not one single contour corresponding to largest rectangle. So the solution is 
1. either resize you image to lower dimension, like I resized you image by

```
resize(srcGray, srcGray, Size(), 0.25, 0.25);
```

and I got this output

[image]

2. You can merge nearby contours in high resolution pics
   refer to this post for merging

[(opencv) merge contours together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801545/opencv-merge-contours-together)

But I would suggest better solution is to resize and then apply the same code. Its easy and less time complex.
NOte the output here corresponds to inner rectangle, you can further adjust resizing factor and canny threshold factor

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realized that high res images would have too much details to find a contour. Now I understand why my coded work on other images which have a more complex background.